# i want to find first integer value from varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

i have below data in table.

```
ID
test_SQL_01
test_SQL_02_PQR_01
test_SQL_03_055
test_SQL_04_ABC_99
```

i want Output like below.

```
ID
01
02
03
04
```

Comment: SQL Server 2016 or SQL Server 2017?

Comment: @DavidG SQL Server 2017

Comment: So why did you tag 2016 too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method can handle embedded numbers of different length

Testdata:

```
DECLARE @t table(ID varchar(50))
INSERT @t values
('1'),
('2abc'),
('a3'),
('test_SQL_01'),
('test_SQL_02_PQR_01'),
('test_SQL_03_055'),
('test_SQL_04_ABC_99')
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  STUFF(LEFT(ID, patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', ID + 'x')), 1, 
    patindex('%[^0-9][0-9]%', ID), '')
FROM @t
```

Result:

```
1
2
3
01
02
03
04
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `INTERGER` value has always 2 digits then yo can do :

```
select substring(ID, patindex('%[0-9]%', ID), 2) as ID
from table t;
```